# can we change textview being on same fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing a demo app where i have to update the texview of an item in recyclerview whenever i change the value of edittext in the same item of recycler view. Following is my rcv adapter.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterU (val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder>() {
    var _binding: UploadItemViewBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder {

        val v =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.upload_item_view, parent, false)
        _binding = UploadItemViewBinding.bind(v)
        return ViewHolder(binding.root)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {


        bindItems(dataList[position])
        holder.getStock()
        holder.updateStockDetail()

    }
    fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) {

        binding.itemquant.text = data.item_quant
        binding.uploadItemName.text = data.item_name
        binding.uploadMfg.text = data.mfg
        binding.skuStock.setText(data.item_stock.toString())
        binding.skuCode.setText(data.sku_code)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var stockdetail = ArrayList<ModelClass>()

        fun getStock() {

            binding.skuStock.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                    for (i in 0 until RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected.size){
                        if (editable.toString().trim()!=""){
                            var x= editable.toString().trim().toInt()
                            RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].item_stock=x
                        }
                    }


                }

            })
        }

        fun updateStockDetail(){
            binding.skuCode.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
                override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {


                }
                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                    if (editable.length==3){

                    var x:String
                    for (i in 0 until RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected.size){
                        if (editable.toString().trim()!=""){
                            x=editable.toString().trim()
                            RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code=x
                            println("$x in if")

                        }
                    }
                    println(RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code)
                    getUpdatedDetails(RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code)
                        for (i in stockdetail){
                            bindItems(i)

                            //binding.uploadItemName.text=i.item_name
                            println(i.item_name)
                        }
       
                }
                }

            })
        }


        fun getUpdatedDetails(skucode:String){
            val call: Call<List<ModelClass>>? =
                ApiClient.instance?.myApi?.getfromsku(skucode)!!
            call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ModelClass>?> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>,
                    response: Response<List<ModelClass>?>
                ) {
                    val skuDetails=response.body()

                    stockdetail.clear()
                    if (skuDetails != null) {
                        for (i in skuDetails){
                            println(i.item_name)
                            stockdetail.addAll(skuDetails)
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>, t: Throwable) {
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

check out updatestockdetail function. Not sure if i am doing the right way.. if its not right can someone help me in doing it the right way?.

Detailed explanation of problem.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYZFL.png)
in this image B20 is sku code for Bingo20gm. in the same way, L20 is for Lays20gm, so if i change B20 to L20 the textview that is showing Bingo 20gm should change to Lays 20gm.
data is being delivered by API, which i am calling in getupdateddetails(), and putting them in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a code review question, but you're overcomplicating this I think.

When you're using a `RecyclerView` (or any list widget really) you have three parts:

- your data
- the thing that displays the data (a `RecyclerView` in this case)
- the thing that takes data and works out *how* to display it (the `Adapter`)

In a `RecyclerView`, the data gets displayed in mini layouts called `ViewHolder`s. Instead of creating one for each item, a pool of them gets created, and when a `ViewHolder` scrolls out of view it gets *recycled* (reused) to display a new item - which is why it's called a `RecyclerView` (as opposed to a `ListView`)

So each `ViewHolder` is a thing that can display details for an item, and when `onBindViewHolder` is called, that's when the adapter works out how to represent your **data** using the **view holder** - things like setting text, images, colours, checked status etc. You can also stick some variables in the `ViewHolder` and set those during binding, so you have more info about what it's currently displaying - setting a `position` variable is common. That way, you can put some code in the `ViewHolder` that works with the data it currently represents.

---

Point is, you can make the `ViewHolder` this self-contained component that:

- has an `EditText` and a `TextView`
- sets a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText` when it's created
- updates the `TextView` whenever the `EditText` content changes

That's all internal to the `ViewHolder`, it's just wiring up the components in its own layout

---

If you need the `ViewHolder` to push some information (like your entered text, or a "button clicked" event) you probably want to put a function in your adapter that it can call:

```
fun updateThing(data: String, position: Int) {
    // update your data sources, do any validation, etc
    // call notifyDataSetChanged() or similar, if required
}
```

If you have a `position` variable in your `ViewHolder` (that you set during `onBindViewHolder`) then the VH just needs to pass that when calling the function. Hey, here's an update, I'm showing position X and here's the new data. That way, the VH is just concerned with UI stuff, and all the data logic is kept separate in the adapter - and that can do things like deciding whether the list needs to update.

---

The other reason for doing that, is that the adapter handles updates from *other* sources too, like your API call. So it's much easier if all your data update logic is in one place, handled by one thing. That way, whatever the source of the update, whatever the reason is for needing an update, it's all done the same way. And if the adapter decides that the data has changed, and the display needs to update, that happens through the normal methods - i.e. `onBindViewHolder` gets called, where you set the current data on the `RecyclerView`. So you can get this chain of events:

- `EditText` on `ViewHolder` updates
- `TextWatcher` code calls the adapter's `updateThing` function with the new data
- the adapter stores the new data and forces a display update
- `onBindViewHolder` gets called and displays the (now changed) data
- the `ViewHolder`'s `TextView` is set to show the new data

so in this case, you don't need to directly modify the `TextView` at all, you just update the data, and as part of that process the new data will just get displayed. Because that's what should happen when the data is changed, whatever caused it to change. And you don't need to worry about what caused it, you just display it!

---

That was a long answer and I obviously haven't rewritten your code, but hopefully it gives you a better idea of how this works and how you can separate things and simplify them. You have a lot of code in your `ViewHolder` that manipulates data, pokes around at the adapter, iterates over all the items in it etc. - it should really just display stuff and react to UI events. Messing with the data is the adapter's job

Comment: Hey @cactusictacs , I loved the explanation, and i understand , changing the data itself instead of textview is a better idea, but I am still unable to reflect that in the viewholder. Even though in my case there is no need to update the data for the adapter, cause data I have to forward from here is a different datatype.  Is it possible for you to explain it with the code, I am unable to implemet rebinding while being on the same holder, my data is being changed at the global level(ob.dataselected), but its not reflected in ItemView.

Comment: @SyedAhad There's no `ob.dataselected` in your code here. But regardless, your **adapter** is responsible for taking **data** and **displaying** it. If that data changes, the adapter needs to know about it, so it can redisplay the current data (and that would include updating the ``TextView``). It won't update automatically or anything. So it makes sense to create an "update data" function in the adapter - that way it knows what's happening, it can update any internal state and redisplay, and if there's an external set of data to update (e.g. storing in a database) it can take care of that too

Comment: Hey @cactusictacs , I followed your explanation and I am able to do the needful, but there is a issue, i cant change my edittext more than once. It crashes saying  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{2673461 VFED..... ......ID 0,126-1080,1501 #7f0801f0 app:id/recyclerViewU}, adapter:..........."
Do you have idea , what might be causing this? Also Thanks a lot for the whole explanation.

Comment: @SyedAhad not sure, you should create another question about it (and post the full stacktrace because you can't tell what's happening from that one line)

Comment: @cactusictacs Sure, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-working with your code, but some things didn't make sense, for example `RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected`. Where are you getting the `RecyclerViewAdapter` instance from?

Hence, I've pasted below a snippet of an adapter code which I had written sometime ago which solves exactly the same purpose as you require.

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    val interactionListener: InteractionListener,
    val onTextChangedListener: OnTextChangedListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.OptionViewHolder>() {

    private val variantsList = ArrayList<VariantsItem>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OptionViewHolder {
        val binding = SellVariantRowItemBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return OptionViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OptionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(variantsList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = variantsList.size

    fun updateVariantsList(newList: ArrayList<VariantsItem>) {
        variantsList.clear()
        variantsList.addAll(newList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class OptionViewHolder(
        private val binding: SellVariantRowItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        private var subVariant: String = ""

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(variantsItem: VariantsItem) {
            subVariant = variantsItem.subVariant

            binding.apply {
                binding.root.tag = "pos_$bindingAdapterPosition"
                sizeTv.text = "Size (${bindingAdapterPosition+1})"
                variantValue.text = variantsItem.variant
                subVariantValue.text = variantsItem.subVariant
                quantityET.setText(variantsItem.quantity.toString().takeIf { it != "0" }?:"1")
                sellingPriceET.setText(variantsItem.listingPrice.toString())
                marketPriceET.setText(variantsItem.labelPrice.toString())

                setOnClickListeners(variantsItem)
                setTextChangeListeners(variantsItem)

            }
        }

        private fun setTextChangeListeners(item: VariantsItem) {
            binding.apply {
                quantityET.addTextChangedListener {
                    if (it.toString().toIntOrNull() != null) {
                        onTextChangedListener.onQuantityChanged(
                            bindingAdapterPosition,
                            item.subVariant, item.variant,
                            it.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }

                marketPriceET.addTextChangedListener {
                    if (it.toString().toIntOrNull() != null) {
                        onTextChangedListener.onMarketPriceChanged(
                            bindingAdapterPosition,
                            item.subVariant,item.variant,
                            it.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }

                sellingPriceET.addTextChangedListener {
                    if (it.toString().toIntOrNull() != null){
                        onTextChangedListener.onSellingPriceChanged(
                            bindingAdapterPosition,
                            item.subVariant,item.variant,
                            it.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun setOnClickListeners(variantsItem: VariantsItem) {
            binding.apply {
                deleteVariantBtn.setSafeOnClickListener {
                    interactionListener.onDeleteCard(variantsItem)
                }

                subVariantLayout.setSafeOnClickListener {
                    interactionListener.onChangeSubVariant(variantsItem)
                }
                variantLayout.setSafeOnClickListener {
                    interactionListener.onChangeVariant(variantsItem)
                }
                addNewVariant.setSafeOnClickListener {
                    it.pan()
                    interactionListener.onAddVariant(variantsItem.subVariant)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface InteractionListener{
        fun onChangeSubVariant(subToBeDeleted: VariantsItem)
        fun onChangeVariant(variant: VariantsItem)
        fun onDeleteCard(variant: VariantsItem)
        fun onAddVariant(subVariantValue: String)
    }

    interface OnTextChangedListener{
        fun onQuantityChanged(position: Int, subVariant: String, variant: String, quantity: String)
        fun onMarketPriceChanged(position: Int, subVariant: String, variant: String, price: String)
        fun onSellingPriceChanged(position: Int, subVariant: String, variant: String, price: String)
    }
}
```

Few things to note:

1. You cannot have a single `binding` instance to handle all of the items of the recycler view. We have the `ViewHolder` for this purpose.
2. Keep your binding logic and everything related to each individual item inside the ViewHolder. That's what it is meant for.
3. Try keeping your adapter simple and only write presentation logic. Keep all of the business logic outside the adapter.
4. Interfaces are your best friends. This supports point 3. Make your activity / fragment implement these interfaces and pass the instance to the Adapter constructor as such `val variantsAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this, this)`. This will allow you to write your business logic outside the Recycler View adapter (Including context required statements like calling a different activity or starting a service or as in your case, making an API call)

Feel free to reach out in case you have any questions.